# jQuery remove text from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a possible way in jQuery to remove a specified value from an input? Like this:

Example:

```
 <input type="text" name="test[]" value="Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5">
```

The button:

```
<button>Click to remove page 4</button>
```

After:

```
<input type="text" name="test[]" value="Page1, Page2, Page3, Page5">
```

Comment: That would be possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: As @Sanpopo wrote, it is. however, it's not a value but a sub-string. try to be more specific as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="someput" name="test[]" value="Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5">
```

JS

```
var new_val = $("#someput").val();
new_val = new_val.replace("what to replace", "");
$("#someput").val(new_val);
```